# 15:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'for'

Tags: java, arrays, token

This error appears to the following code:

```java
int array [50];
int i = 0;

void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() 
{
  Serial.println ("Position " + array[i]);
  delay (2000);

}

for (i <= 50) 
{
  int n = random (251); // Random number from 0 to 250
  array[i] = n;
  i++;
}

// Bubble sort function
void sort (int a[], int size) 
{
    for(int i=0; i<(size-1); i++) 
    {
        for(int j=0; j<(size-(i+1)); j++) 
        {
                if(a[j] > a[j+1]) 
                {
                    int k = a[j];
                    a[j] = a[j+1];
                    a[j+1] = k;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

When I put the for loop in the function void loop like this :

```java
void loop() 
{
  Serial.println ("Position " + array[i]);
  delay (2000);

  for (i <= 50) 
  {
    int n = random (251); // Random number from 0 to 250
    array[i] = n;
    i++;
  }
}
```

It gives me :

```
exit status 1
expected ';' before ')' token
```

I'm just trying to stay on top of work while on holiday but I seem to have gotten dumber in these couple of months ..

thank you for your help

Comment: You should add a tag for the language/platform your using, `for (i <= 50) ` looks incomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the language (C, Java, C++, PHP, ...) the for loops is usually of this form:

```
for (init_part; condition; post_instructions) {
  ...
}
```

If you don't have anything to initialize or a post instruction, can omit them:

```
void loop() 
{
  Serial.println ("Position " + array[i]);
  delay (2000);
  for ( ; i <= 50; ) 
  {
    int n = random (251); // Random number from 0 to 250
    array[i] = n;
    i++;
  }
}
```

The 'i++' can go to the post_instructions, eg:

```
void loop() 
{
  Serial.println ("Position " + array[i]);
  delay (2000);
  for ( ; i <= 50; ++i) 
  {
    int n = random (251); // Random number from 0 to 250
    array[i] = n;
  }
}
```

[edit] by the way, you don't have a 'i' variable in the scope. You might have to declare it before...

Answer (score 0):

According to the other for loop you have:

```
for (int i=0; i <= 50; i++;) 
{
  int n = random (251); // Random number from 0 to 250
  array[i] = n;     
}
```